# Send a sms with my phone number to another phone number automatically (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode

the title is not very clear. I want to send a sms with my phone number to a user when he tap on a button. Imagine my phone number is xxxx. The user phone number is yyyy. I want to send a sms to yyyy from xxxx when this user tap on the button. It is possible ?

I guess I must use a database or something like this to notify my phone to send a sms when user tap on the button.

Comment: You may a server on your side that will receive the sms send action . This server will then send the sms to user. It may be possible to set your number in this message.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using Apple's built-in APIs. The only thing you can do is create a pre-populated message via iMessage using UIActivityViewController: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller But the user still needs to send the message themselves.

If you want to send a message you can use a 3rd party SMS API like Twilio.